# array vs vector

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Seems like in AS3, I can in theory, delare arrays that can only contain certain data types:

```
private var my_array:Array.<String>;
```

produces this error:
1199: type parameters with a non-parameterized type

however

```
private var my_vector:Vector.<String>;
```

is just fine.

Is there a way of making this work with an Array?

Comment: what is that you are trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I would like to declare arrays while specifying what type they are. Like an array of strings, an array numbers, etc...

Comment: That's what a `Vector` is for. A strongly typed array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[ArrayElementType("String")] 
public var newStringProperty:Array;

[ArrayElementType("Number")] 
public var newNumberProperty:Array;
```

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=metadata_3.html
unfortunately, such arrays don't provide access to methods of their element type like vectors do:

```
var strings:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
strings.push('hello world');
trace(strings[0].charAt(2));
```

Comment: That metadata tag only applies to MXML array definitions. It's effectively a compile-time constraint, not a runtime enforcement. And won't do anything if used in an as class.

Comment: it'll do nothing in a pure as3 project, it worked for me in an .as class extending `UIComponent`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no.

The "Generic" syntax is a one-off that was only given to `Vector`.  It makes me sad.  I'd use generics all over the place if I could.

Here is more [discussion on the issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848365/why-doesnt-actionscript-have-generics)

Answer (score 2):

Arrays do not take type declarations at all at this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass elements of array to constructor. If you need parameterized "array",  use vector.